# Playing video in webview

Tags: android, flash, webview, html5-video

I would like to build an app that accesses youtube.com/tv in a webview for android set top boxes. I can get it to work by loading with [html5webview](http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/) but it takes for ever. I have noticed that this is the way the android browser does it. I have been using opera mobile lately and have noticed that it runs flawlessly, it also states in opera that my pugins are not enabled.

Question 1: How is opera Mobile rendering video on youtube.com/tv, does it ship with its own flash?

Question 2 What is the best way to implement this? I have reverted my code to basic webView for fresh start.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class TvbrowserActivity extends Activity
{
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    String ua = " Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19";
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com/tv");
}
}
```

I also have hardware accelerated set in activity in android manifest

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a `WebView`, and not just a `VideoView`?

Comment: You should use the official youtube API instead https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 0):

Check if the code is helpful or not

```
  myWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView );
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings(); 
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/v/nVLcujAj67g?version=3");
```

Comment: Tried playing this video and it played well, I want to keep the TV interface should I rewrite urls to use that player the urls for tv are

Comment: tried the code it appears that auto play and also fullscreen is breaking the  player